# EndsWith within acrobat pdf form

Tags: java, function, pdf, acrobat

I try to create a writeable PDF form using Acrobat Pro DC. I want to validate that an entry is finishing with a right suffix (XXYY). If it is not, I want an alert to pop up with the message, "Fullfill with the right license XXYY."

Using the helpful message [How to validate PDF form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760154/how-to-validate-pdf-form), I have written the following code :

```
if ( EndsWith(event.value) != "XXYY"){ 
    event.rc = false;
    app.alert({
        cMsg: "Fullfill with the right license XXYY",
        cTitle: "My Window Title",
        nIcon: 0,
        nType: 1
    });
}
```

But it does not work in pdf form : using debugger, I receive the message "TypeError: EndsWith is not a function".

What could I do to improve the code?

Comment: If I am right, this is using Spidermonkey 1.8 engine. the documentation doesn't seem to illustrate that Endwith is a valid string function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference#Strings

Comment: thanks for your comment that seems right. I understand I can neither use another function like substring. Would it be possible to implement the function "EndsWith" in Acrobat ? And how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the endsWith polyfill to a document level script in the PDF and then all other scripts will be able to use it.

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(search, this_len) {
    if (this_len === undefined || this_len > this.length) {
      this_len = this.length;
    }
    return this.substring(this_len - search.length, this_len) === search;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added a bunch of string related polyfills to my PDFs. It's like upgrading the JS engine without needing Adobe to do it.